# concatenating in sequential order multiple mp3 files into 1 mp3 file in JAVA

Tags: java, audio, mp3

Let's say I have **multiple mp3** files and I want combine them as **1 mp3** file or save as 1 mp3 file in **JAVA**.

any ideas?

thanks!

Comment: I do not know what do you mean when you say "combine". I can imagine the following meanings:

 1. concatenate several streams
 2. mix them up (for example music and singing) 
 3. create multi-stream file (that contains several streams)

Comment: @AlexR i mean concatenating in sequential order

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use [JLayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html).  This is an older library but is reportedly stable.  Browsing the api it seems like there may be a way to accomplish your task.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62618/what-is-the-best-way-to-merge-mp3-files) seems to have a few more options that you could also investigate.

If you can convert the files to .wav format before you load them into a Java program then maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653861/join-two-wav-files-from-java) past question could help.

Is there a reason you need to use Java?  Tools like FFmpeg can do wonders, although the learning curve can be a little steep.

Comment: actually this task is a part of some java project, thatss why I'm using java :) thank you for your answer!