# Concatenating mp3 files in android

Tags: java, android, mp3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to merge mp3 files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62618/what-is-the-best-way-to-merge-mp3-files)

I need to Concatenate mp3 files in my app. Like a.pm3 + b.mp3= ab.mp3 . 
Any idea how to achieve this in android.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/62762/1134705

Comment: Thanx Asok. But How to use that mp3wrap in android.