# merging mp3 file in android

Tags: android, merge, mp3

I am developing an application in which i want to merge multiple .mp3 file in a single .mp3 file I searched a lot but unable to find any solution. Is there any way to do this then please let me know. thanks in advance.

Comment: Get some hints [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62618/what-is-the-best-way-to-merge-mp3-files)

Comment: hi, i want to merge two mp3 audio files into one mp3 file..for example  1st one is 1min and 2nd is 45 sec then the output should be as 1min ..if u know please help me to solve it.thanks in advance..