# join multiple audios file in android

Tags: android, join, audio, ffmpeg, merge

I need to join multiple audio files into one sequence audio file.

like:

```
audio-A.mp3 length is [00:00:00 to 00:02:06]
audio-B.mp3 length is [00:00:00 to 00:01:02]

require output is audio-A.mp3 + audio-B.mp3
like this: audio-A.mp3 [00:00:00 to 00:02:06] + audio-B.mp3 [00:02:07 to 00:03:09]
total timing is [00:03:09]
```

Does anyone have any solutions to this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? (possible duplicate)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21381585/concatenate-mp3-files-in-java

Answer (score 0):

if you know ffmpeg. this task will be very easy for you

```
ffmpeg -i audio-A.mp3 -i audio-B.mp3  -filter_complex 'concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[a]' -map '[a]' -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 256k output.mp3
```

you can

set your codec from ffmpeg list  `-codec:a`

`-b:a` using this you can alter bitrate